# Please help me send a jpg file using send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following tags in my html.erb to both display and download a jpg file that is not in the public/images folder:

```
<%= image_tag retrieve_photo_path(@photo) %>
<%= link_to "Download Photo", download_photo_path(@photo) %>
```

my controller code looks like:

```
def retrieve
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  send_data File.read(@photo.abs_filepath), :type = "image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline"
end

def download
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  send_file @photo.abs_filepath, :type = "image/jpeg", :filename => @photo.filename
end
```

The download link works perfectly, but the image tag displays a red x (broken image).  What am I missing?  I'm using InstantRails on WinXP, updated to Rails 2.3.4 and Ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: Check your server logs or output for the request to the "retreive" action. You'll likely find some error messages there that may help you figure it out.

Comment: If I type the url "www.mytestapp.com/photos/3/retrieve" directly into my browser (IE) to simulte the img request, I get the red x broken image -- and my apache access.log has the following entry:
"GET /photos/3/retrieve HTTP/1.1" 304 0
can anyone help with what that status code 304 means?

Comment: it looks like it has something to do with Apache caching, but I am not familiar with that at all -- please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not reading the file data properly, you need to open the file first.

Modify your `retrieve` action as follows:

```
def retrieve
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  File.open(@photo.abs_filepath, 'rb') do |f|
    send_data f.read, :type => "image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline"
  end
end
```

Comment: hallelujah! that was it!  Interesting that I didn't get an error message.