# send PDF with rails send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I use ruby 1.9.3 and redmine 1.4.4

According to this -> [Please help me send a jpg file using send_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698386/please-help-me-send-a-jpg-file-using-send-data) , I do that in a controller:

```
  @file = temp.path
  File.open(@file, 'r') do |f|
    send_data f.read, :filename => "myfile.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
  end
  File.delete(@file)
```

But it returns `ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)`, why ?

Comment: `send_file` doesn't work?

Comment: send_file works but I want to do `File.delete(@file)` in the end. I edit my question.

Comment: Why can't you send the file with `send_file` and then delete?

Comment: because it send me a damage pdf... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933871/clean-tmp-when-send-file-is-over

Comment: When using `send_file`, you don't need `File.open do |f|` etc. You can just do `send_file @file, :disposition => "attachment"`. Did you try that?

Comment: If I do `send_file temp.path, :disposition => "attachment"` and `File.delete(temp.path)` I have a damage PDF and I can't open it. Same with `temp.close temp.unlink` instead of File.delete. 
 
I use send_data because I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232088/in-ruby-on-rails-after-send-file-method-delete-the-file-from-server) and the first answer is exacly what I want to do: "You can try using send_data instead, which will block until the data is sent, allowing your File.delete request to succeed". But it doesn't work with me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The PDF file has to be encoded

```
 file = temp.path
 File.open(file, 'r') do |f|
   send_data f.read.force_encoding('BINARY'), :filename => filename, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
 end
 File.delete(file)
```